# Is the interval [0,1) compact within itself?

Tags: real-analysis

this is my first time using this site to ask a question so sorry if I accidentally violate some rules/customs.

My question is if the interval [0,1) is a compact metric space as a subest of itself (using the Euclidean metric).

I have learnt that a space is compact if and only if it is closed and totally bounded (and, as I understand it, totally bounded is equivalent to bounded in this case). This set appears to be both closed and bounded. However, I am pretty sure it is not compact because the sequence (1-1/n) converges to 1, so any subsequence must also converge to 1. But 1 is not in the space so this is a counter example.

I was thinking about why the closed and bounded theorem might not apply and the theorem seems to require the set in question to be a subset of the reals to apply. I was wondering if this is why the theorem might not apply.

Also, I was informed that the set is in fact compact as a subset of itself but I really don't think that is correct.

Have I missed something here? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: $[0,1)=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1-1/n)$. The characterization of compact metric spaces is 'complete and totally bounded' Your non-convergent Cauchy sequence shows that it is not complete.

Comment: Oh gosh is it complete instead of closed? I apologize for messing that up. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: Every space is closed in itself. I think its clearer now anyways.

Comment: Yes, thanks everyone for the help!